# How to turn a raw.gz image file into a bootable ISO?

Tags: linux, boot, usb, iso-image, bootable-media

I have a `raw.gz` custom image file that was an image capture someone sent to me. I was able to use Rufus put this on to a USB and boot from it, however I am trying to turn the file into a bootable ISO.

When using Rufus to create a bootable USB, there is not letter drive associated with the USB anymore after the Rufus formatting is done, however you can use it to boot from UEFI. If I can convert this file into a bootable ISO (similar to how a red hat 7 ISO is), I would be able to create recognizable USB's for recreation and network deployment.

I have tried multiple things and I am able to create an ISO out of the image using red hat 7.5 mkisofs, however the ISO file is not bootable. I have done some research and it seems that the issue is there is no method for this ISO to boot, and one must be associated with it. I have tried the following :

```
mkisofs -b isolinux.bin -c boot.cat -no-emul-boot -o genertatedIso.iso 
/makeiso
```

where `/makeiso` is the directory off of root. I get the following error message when trying this:

```
genisoimage: Uh oh, I cant find the boot image 'isolinux.bin' !
```

If someone could please advise as to how I can accomplish the goal of turning my ISO into a bootable it would be greatly appreciated.